# Nested If - Possible better solution?

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I am hoping to get some advice on a better solution to a massive nested `If` statement in VBA.  Becasue of the amount of conditions that would be possible the `If` statement is becoming extremely large.  I was thinking of using a `For` loop, but that seems like it would still require a significant amount of `If` conditions, and I also thought of a `Select Case`, but that doesnt really work either.

The code below shows how I have the variables set for the `If` statements and most of the conditions.  Any help in streamlining this code would be greatly appreciated.

```
    If wsCalc.Range("LenderComplete") <> vbNullString Then f = 1
If wsCalc.Range("ProcessorComplete") <> vbNullString Then g = 1
If wsCalc.Range("KeyerComplete") <> vbNullString Then h = 1
If wsCalc.Range("CheckerComplete") <> vbNullString Then i = 1

If f <> 1 And g <> 1 And h <> 1 And i <> 1 Then
    ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
    With ContLoanFile.Label7
        .Caption = "Lender items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Processor items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Checker items NOT complete."
        .Font.Size = 9
    End With
    If f = 1 And g <> 1 And h <> 1 And i <> 1 Then
        ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
        With ContLoanFile.Label7
            .Caption = "Lender items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Processor items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Checker items NOT complete."
            .Font.Size = 9
        End With
        If f = 1 And g = 1 And h <> 1 And i <> 1 Then
            ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
            With ContLoanFile.Label7
                .Caption = "Lender items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Processor items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Checker items NOT complete."
                .Font.Size = 9
            End With
            If f = 1 And g = 1 And h = 1 And i <> 1 Then
                ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
                With ContLoanFile.Label7
                    .Caption = "Lender items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Processor items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Checker items NOT complete."
                    .Font.Size = 9
                End With
                If f = 1 And g = 1 And h = 1 And i = 1 Then
                    ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
                    With ContLoanFile.Label7
                        .Caption = "Lender items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Processor items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Checker items COMPLETE."
                        .Font.Size = 9
                    End With
                    If f <> 1 And g = 1 And h = 1 And i = 1 Then
                        ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
                        With ContLoanFile.Label7
                            .Caption = "Lender items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Processor items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Checker items COMPLETE."
                            .Font.Size = 9
                        End With
                        If f = 1 And g <> 1 And h = 1 And i = 1 Then
                            ContLoanFile.ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
                            With ContLoanFile.Label7
                                .Caption = "Lender items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Processor items NOT complete." & vbNewLine & "Keyer items COMPLETE." & vbNewLine & "Checker items COMPLETE."
                                .Font.Size = 9
                            End With
```

Comment: Instead of all the AND statements to check if nothing is one, you could just as well check if the sum of all 4 is smaller then 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, they don't need to be nested because they all have conflicting logic and will never "cascade" down like a nested `If` is intended to do.

```
If f <> 1 And g <> 1 And h <> 1 And i <> 1 Then '// If this is true
    '...
    If f = 1 And g <> 1 And h <> 1 And i <> 1 Then '// Then this can never be true
```

If you were going to keep this design then it should really be `If...ElseIf...` logic in place.

---

Secondly, you have a lot of common logic so something like this should work because you don't have to repeat the same outcome for every condition:

```
Dim caption As String

caption = "Lender items " & IIf(wsCalc.Range("LenderComplete").Value <> vbNullString, "COMPLETE", "NOT complete") & vbNewLine & _
          "Processor items " & IIf(wsCalc.Range("ProcessorComplete").Value <> vbNullString, "COMPLETE", "NOT complete") & vbNewLine & _
          "Keyer items " & IIf(wsCalc.Range("KeyerComplete").Value <> vbNullString, "COMPLETE", "NOT complete") & vbNewLine & _
          "Checker items " & IIf(wsCalc.Range("CheckerComplete").Value <> vbNullString, "COMPLETE", "NOT complete")


With ContLoanFile
    .ContinueLP.BackColor = vbYellow
    With .Label7
        .Caption = caption
        .Font.Size = 9
    End With
End With
```

No need for a loop and no need to test the same values multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I still have a lot to learn in VBA, but y'all help my knowledge increase significantly.  Thank you again.

Comment: Not a problem, we all started somewhere :)